# Beautiful Soup - Any specified encoding breaks prettify formatting

Tags: python, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to just write out formatted html from a website to a file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

from os import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  url = sys.argv[1]
  print(url)
else:
  url = "www.niceme.me"

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
content = http.request("GET", url).data
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

outputFile = open("output.html", 'w')
outputFile.truncate()
outputFile.write(str(soup.prettify("UTF-8")))
```

I have the "UTF-8" parameter passed into `prettify` to avoid "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position..." errors, as that's what I read I needed to do. The issue is, ANY form of encoding I pass in essentially undoes the `prettify` and just writes/prints everything in one, single line of text, where each new line is represented as "\n". This happens for

```
soup.prettify().encode("UTF-8")
```

as well.

I've also tried defining soup as:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(content.decode("UTF-8", "ignore"))`

...but that doesn't work either.
I can't seem to figure anything out or find a solution, and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I GOT IT, FINALLY

I needed to open the file as binary writable...

`outputFile = open("output.html", 'wb')`